# Does the self change iff there is a change in knowledge?

Tags: epistemology, knowledge, identity, self

While still being distinct terms. And is there a term for this? Hope that’s enough to go on!

Comment: If you assume there're 2 types of selfs (ego-like and soul-like) then a change of the usual concrete knowledge can possibly change your ego-like self if it's impressive enough to any of your constituent part of your ego, but no effect to the other self. Why? The former is simply from the [tree of knowledge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_of_the_knowledge_of_good_and_evil) which brought about the task of [beirurim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tohu_and_Tikun), while the latter is emanated from the tree of life such as described by Kabbalah's [Sefirot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sefirot)

Comment: Does a physical change to the brain or its function -- say disease, trauma, drug -- count as a *change of knowledge*?

Comment: @Michael Doesn't any change in qualia impart new knowledge? Assuming the person is still subjectively experiencing, then both their knowledge and self would change.

Comment: Does *knowledge* exist beyond physical (chemical, electrical, structural)? Does *self* exist beyond physical? If only self exists beyond physical, but not knowledge, then some part of self is non-knowledge. If so, can that non-knowledge part change, or is it static?

Comment: No. The self can change its non-cognitive aspects, such as emotional attitudes and dispositions to act. And no, this is not enough to go on for a cogent answer on this site. Maybe enough for a discussion forum like [Philosophy Forum](https://thephilosophyforum.com/).

Comment: @Michael I think the self is always changing, in that knowledge cannot be halted. You hear or don’t hear your dog bark, in either case you know something, someone’s at the door, or not. These two different “branches” lead to two different selves. One with a tighter bond with their dog and one more engrossed in their book.

Comment: I make no argument here against the self as continually changing. The clarification sought is whether any aspects of the self exist beyond knowledge, and if so, whether those aspects can change.

Comment: @Conifold But doesn't self include an awareness of emotions and dispositions to different acts? I wont keep discussing here just wanted that one clarification.

Comment: Certainly not in many cases, people often emote and act unwittingly, and only reflect on it later, if at all. But even if we were perfectly self-aware, change in attitude is quite distinct from change in knowledge. Nothing in one's knowledge changes when they go from enthusiastically lying to feeling bad about it and tending to lie less.

Comment: @Conifold I had in mind acting unwittingly would take someone out of (self) awareness, and upon regaining awareness they would reflect and the self would change to the degree they reflect.

Comment: You're describing the subtle interaction between the two selfs, there're potentially (huge) differences between awareness and self-awareness (for example to see and thus aware of some blood and then aware of the fact the blood is your own blood). Ethics is from the latter self, not from the ego-like self...

Comment: @DoubleKnot alright I’m open to “self” being made of more than one thing. Seems that’s the best avenue for me to explore/learn.

Comment: The self has already changed by the time they'll get to reflecting, if they ever will.

Answer (score 1):

When we sleep can our self sleep...?...sleep holding on to our ego  tightly...? Can you say your self changes if there is a change in knowledge?

The soul is usually called the Self. If you like perennial philosophy, I invite you to read the Bhagavad Gita.

The changes occur after knowing about something (change in knowledge) may be in your perception, emotions, thoughts, attitudes, behavior, etc.; but not in the soul.  You will see its explanation in the second chapter.  Soul is always pure. No purification is needed to it. It is a misconception to say that the soul changes.

https://www.swami-krishnananda.org/bgita/Commentary_Bhagavadgita.pdf

https://researchspace.ukzn.ac.za/bitstream/handle/10413/7386/Rajamani_S_1995.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y

Comment: I know very little eastern philosophy so I I’m glad to hear I may find some insight.